# Ldap3 lib python run ldif

Tags: python, ldif

I am using Apache directory studio to import ldif to update some eDirectory records. i would like to know whether we can use ladp3 lib by python to make this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is LDIF parser example from [ldif module documentation](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldif.html):

```
import sys
from ldif import LDIFParser,LDIFWriter

SKIP_DN = ["uid=foo,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com",
   "uid=bar,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"]

class MyLDIF(LDIFParser):
   def __init__(self,input,output):
      LDIFParser.__init__(self,input)
      self.writer = LDIFWriter(output)

   def handle(self,dn,entry):
      if dn in SKIP_DN:
        return
      self.writer.unparse(dn,entry)

parser = MyLDIF(open("input.ldif", 'rb'), sys.stdout)
parser.parse()
```